# Closure properties of the class of inherently ambiguous CFLs

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

is set of inherently ambiguous context free languages close under operations such that union, intersection, kleene star, concatenation, reverse, complementation and etc. how many of theme are answered?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: It's hard problem for homework. I don't think there is a university in world that ask this problem for bachelor of science student. a problem over class of languages that membership of it is undecidable. I was study closure if regular, deterministic context free, linear grammar and RE and R and etc. there was no topic and problem such this in Peter Linz and Michael Sipser book. and of course I pass Introduction to computation theory and theory of computation courses in university. so I don't have homework. I was just interesting in this problem while rereading Peter Linz book. @Raphael

Comment: and there is similar question in cs stackexchange [link](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42477/closure-properties-of-linear-context-free-languages) if there is some reference that could help me find answer tell me and introduce some books. @Raphael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Reversal

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages *is* closed under reversal (exercise).

#### Intersection

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages is *not* closed under intersection. Indeed, take some inherently ambiguous context-free language $L$. Now take $L'$ to be a copy of $L$ which uses a different alphabet. Then $L \cap L' = \emptyset$.

#### Complementation

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages is *not* closed under complementation. Indeed, consider the Goldstine language
$$ G = \{ a^{n_1} b \cdots a^{n_p} b : p \geq 1 \text{ and } n_i \neq i \text{ for some } i \}. $$
This language is context-free and inherently ambiguous (see [slides of Cyril Nicaud](http://algo.inria.fr/pfac/PFAC/Program_files/nicaud.pdf)). Also,
$$
\overline{G} \cap \Sigma^* b = \{ aba^2\cdots a^p b : p \geq 1 \},
$$
which isn't even context-free.

#### Union

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages is *not* closed under union. Indeed, the following variant of the Goldstine language is probably also context-free and inherently ambiguous:
$$ G' = \{ a^{n_1} b \cdots a^{n_p} b : p \geq 1 \text{ and } n_i \neq i+1 \text{ for some } i \}. $$
However, $G \cup G' = (a^*b)^+$.

#### Iteration (Kleene star)

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages is *not* closed under Kleene star. Indeed, consider the following language:
$$
\Omega_3 = \{ u \in \{a,b,c\}^* : |u|_a \neq |u|_b \text{ or } |u|_a \neq |u|_c \}.
$$
Here $|u|_a$ is the number of $a$s in $u$. This language is context-free and inherently ambiguous (see the slides of Cyril Nicaud). However, $\Omega_3^* = \{a,b,c\}^*$.

#### Concatenation

The class of inherently ambiguous context-free languages is *not* closed under concatenation. Indeed, the following variants of $\Omega_3$ are probably also context-free and inherently ambiguous:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Omega'_3 &= \{ u \in \{a,b,c\}^* : |u|_a \neq |u|_b \text{ or } |u|_a \neq |u|_c \text{ or } u = \epsilon \}, \\
\Omega''_3 &= \{ u \in \{a,b,c\}^* : |u|_a \neq |u|_b+1 \text{ or } |u|_a \neq |u|_c+1 \text{ or } u = \epsilon \}.
\end{align*}
$$
However, $\Omega'_3 \Omega''_3 = \{a,b,c\}^*$.

Comment: Hm. Is there an easy way to get a feeling that there should be not too many closure properties? For instance, IACFL is not closed against intersection with regular languages ($G \cap a^*b$) which is a very basic one; do any of these follow? I guess what I'm asking is: how do closure properties relate? Maybe I should ask this in a new post.

Comment: The main idea here is that there is absolutely no reason to expect that IACFL be closed under any non-trivial operation. All you need is a reservoir of examples, and with some work you should be able to find counterexamples. It is certainly possible that you can significantly simplify the counterexamples I list; I didn't try to optimize them at all. What you're suggesting is whether there is one key property which implies many of these non-closure results, and that's indeed an interesting question, though you'd have to come up with more examples of relevant language classes.