# prove that if L is context-free then L' = {w2#w1 | w1#w2∈L} is context-free

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, computation-models

Given that $\#\notin \Sigma$ and $L\subseteq \Sigma^*\#\Sigma^*$, prove that if $L$ is context-free language then $L' = \{w_2\#w_1 \mid w_1\#w_2\in L\}$ is context-free.
I'm trying to prove this in this way:

1. because $L$ is context-free then $G$ is context-free grammar for $L$, then $L(G)=L$.
2. by showing that the reversed grammar $F$ of $G$ is the same grammar of $L$ and because $G$ is context-free then $F$ is context-free then $L(F)=L'$ is also context-free.
   but can't figure out a way to prove this, so I need help to do this.

Comment: Note that $u\in L$ does not mean that the mirror word $\overline{u}\in L'$ (and conversely).

Comment: then I can't prove the question by this way?

Comment: Indeed, I don't think so.

Comment: any hint of another way that can work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique path in the derivation tree that leads from the axiom $S$ to the terminal symbol $\#$. An idea would be to turn this tree upside down along that path.

This solution follows the construction for the [closure under cyclic shift for context-free languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9087/4287), as suggested in the book by Hopcroft and Ullman.

[image: derivation trees]

Comment: What do you mean by "to turn this tree upside-down along that path", is that to switch between the variables from the right side and left side?

Comment: I tried to explain that in the linked answer.

Comment: Yeah, very nice and simple explanation thank you so much!