# Definition of the cyclic shift of a formal language?

Tags: formal-languages

Wikipedia says, the context-free languages are closed under

> the cyclic shift of $L$ (the language $\{vu : uv \in L \}$)

So I am looking for the definition of the cyclic shift operation on formal languages.

From the quote, what are required on $u$ and $v$? Are they in $L$, or in $alphabet(L)^*$? Thanks.

Comment: Also called *cycle* or *conjugation*. On cs.stackexchange the closure has been discussed for [regular](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/prove-that-regular-languages-are-closed-under-the-cycle-operator) and for [context-free](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7831/easy-proof-for-context-free-languages-being-closed-under-cyclic-shift) languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cyclic shift of a language $L$ consists of all cyclic shifts of the words in $L$. Instead of defining the cyclic shift formally, let me give an example. The following are all cyclic shifts of the word `monkey`:

`monkey` `onkeym` `nkeymo` `keymon` `eymonk` `ymonke`

To see the connection with the definition, consider `nkeymo`. If we write `monkey` as `mo` concatenated with `nkey` and then switch both parts, we get `nkeymo`. This corresponds to setting `u=mo` and `v=nkey` in the definition above.

To answer your concrete question, $u,v \in \Sigma^*$. (The alphabet is usually denoted by $\Sigma$.)