# Cut word from regular language into two parts and swap them. Is the language still regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages

> Define language $L’$ for given regular language $L$ as: $$L’=\{uv | u,v\in\Sigma^{*}, vu\in L\}$$ is language $L’$ also regular?

Hello, I need some help with solving this question. 
I need somehow to determine where to divide each word. Or actually - in what state of its automata will that language be. If that makes sense and my understanding of the problem is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that regular languages are closed under the cycle operator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/prove-that-regular-languages-are-closed-under-the-cycle-operator)

Comment: @CodeChef Yes, that's absolutely perfect. Thank you very much, I just wasn't using "right words". Thanks again.